# Integrable Random Variable and Finite Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I would like to verify whether the following statements are equivalent:

> Given a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, a random variable $X$ is integrable IFF it has a finite expectation IFF $E|X|<\infty$.

$E|X|<\infty\iff E(X^++X^-)<\infty\iff EX^++EX^-<\infty$.

This implies, $EX^+<\infty$ and $EX^-<\infty$, which is equivalent to have a finite expectation.

Is it correct to claim:

$X$ integrable $\iff$ $E|X|<\infty\iff$ $X$ has a finite expectation under $P$.

Comment: Yea; extra characters

Comment: @badatmath thank you. I actually think the statements are correct, but my proof is one-sided, so it really isn't a proof.

Comment: What didnt you prove?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is $\mathbb P$ integrable $\iff$ $X$ is measurable and $\mathbb E X^\pm <\infty$ so
$$\mathbb E X=\mathbb E X^+-X^-= \mathbb E X^+ -\mathbb E X^- <\infty $$
and $$ \mathbb E |X| =\mathbb E X^+ + X^- = \mathbb EX^+ + \mathbb E X^- <\infty .$$

And the other way around $$\mathbb E X\leq \mathbb E |X| < \infty$$ since $X^-$ is positive.